# Groovy to create JSON

Tags: json, groovy

Here's an SQL query I had to execute in Groovy:

```
def resultset_bio = sql.rows("SELECT author, isbn FROM Book WHERE genre = 'biography'")
```

I'm trying to convert this data into JSON. For that, I am using this code:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
            json {
                Biographies(resultset_bio.collect{[id: it]})
            }
            println json.toPrettyString()
        }
```

The JSON output I expect should be like this:

```
    {
    "Biographies":
        {
            "SSS": ["XXX",456988]
        }
}
```

But instead, I'm getting this:

```
{
    "Biographies": [
        {
            "id": {
                "author": "XXX",
                "isbn": 456988,
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How should I change my code? Please help.

Comment: You really want one object per field?

Comment: i guess he has to, since there could be more than one book with the same title.  not a great ID imho. i'd rather go with the isbn.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I'm asked to produce an output Json.

Answer (score 1):

Now `id` is passed as a static key.
Try:

```
json {
   Biographies(resultset_bio.collect{[(it.id): it]})
}
```

Comment: Nope. I'm getting a groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: id for class: groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult

Comment: Ok, so substitute `id` with the key you want to put there, is that book title?

Comment: Yes its the book title, and I did substitute id with the book title. But I still get the same result. MissingPropertyException.

Comment: Please check what exactly you get from DB in `resultset_bio`. The keys are uppercase or lowercase? Now you just need to pick the correct column and substitute `id` with it. In your sql query I don't see fetching title column.

Comment: Okay, I just edited my question. The expected Json is now different. My mistake. I apologize.

Comment: Ok, so the key is book title a the value is a list of columns fetched from DB?

Comment: Yes, it's not. It's much better to get it as a map.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the book title in your select so you can't make a mapping of title to book info.

In order to get the list layout of each row (which is a map) grouped by author:

```
def authorBios = resultset_bio.groupBy { it.author }

def biographies = authorBios.collectEntries { author, row ->
     [author, row*.values()] 
}
json {
    Biographies(biographies)
}
```